# Prevent the "Alt Gr" key from producing special characters

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10, special-characters

I'm using windows 10 and I want to use the <kbd>alt gr</kbd> key for setting shortcuts in an application.

The application is successfully interpreting the shortcut, but it doesn't stop the key from inserting the special character; for example, <kbd>alt gr</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> produces `ó`. Is there any way I can stop this?

Answer (score 2):

[Autohotkey](http://ahkscript.org/) could help in your case check their [Overriding or Disabling Hotkeys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Override.htm) section. With Autohotkey you can even disable hotkeys only if a certain window is active.

You can use autohotkey to remap the short cut. This script remaps <kbd>alt gr</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> when Chrome is active.

```
$<^>!o::
IfWinActive ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_1
   Send ^{t}
return
```

The drawback of this solution is, that your app will not receive the original hotkey either. You can use a different hotkey combination for your app to listen to, but the user still only needs to press <kbd>alt gr</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>.

Another possible solution could be to create a custom keyboard layout with the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22339) that does not include the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> combinations that you want to override. That way, you don't have to change the application.